# Faster way of getting all text from a webpage's entire DOM

Tags: java, dom, webdriver, gettext

I'm using WebDriver to retrieve all the text from a page (Note, I want the entire DOM, not just whatever is in the HTML document, so which is why I'm currently using WebDriver).

I create a list of all elements by searching for `By.cssSelector("*")`, and then I loop through all the elements with `getText()`. This works well, the only problem is that it's pretty slow. It takes about ~40 seconds for a complex page. I tried using `"body *"` as the CSS selector to save time, but it only saves maybe 10%. I also use Chrome instead of FF since Chrome does this much faster.

Are there any suggestions for speeding this up? I imagine the browser adds significant overhead, but I don't know other ways to retrieve a webpage`s entire DOM other than WebDriver. From what I've seen, things like Jsoup will only give you the DOM of the HTML document, but a page you see on your browser is more than just the HTML (there could be text coming from js, json, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the browser that is the slowdown, but the interface between your code and it. Under the covers, WebDriver is making a separate HTTP call to the driver (and then passing that through to the browser) for every element you iterate over. Even if that is pretty quick, you're doing it for every single element in the DOM. Try injecting javascript into the browser (via webdriver) to collect all the text and return it as a String back to your code. You can do this with a single WebDriver call.